# JQuery validation custom method not show when false is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have been struggling with this issue for a while.
I am trying to validate a text box for not passing the value **100** if the value in a drop down list is by **percentage**. 
This is my html code:

```
  <input type="number" class="inline-form-input" value="" data-action="Increase_budget"
   name="increaseBudgetByValue" data-review="Increase_budget_by_value" placeholder="Enter value">
   <p>if</p>
    <div class="select_p select_narrow" id="automated-rules-increase-budget-if-unit" data-target="increaseBudgetIfUnit">
     <div class="select">
       <div class="select_in">
        <span data-review="Increase_budget_if_unit">$</span>
       </div>
     </div>
    <div id="ifUnitDDL" class="select_drop">
       <ul>
         <li value="$">$</li>
         <li value="%">%</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have created a custom method to validate the input when It changes and it works fine:

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("lowerThan100Percent", function (value, element, params) {
        debugger;
        return !(parseInt(value) > 100 && ($("span[data-review='Increase_budget_if_unit']").text() === "%" || params.ifUnit === "%"));
    }, "*Cannot pass the 100%");
```

I invoke that function when the user select other list value:

```
$("#ifUnitDDL li")
        .on("click",
            function (e) {
                debugger;
                var ifUnit = $(this).text();
                if (ifUnit === "%") {
                    var element = $("input[name='increaseBudgetIfValue']");
                    var value = element.val();
                    var params = { ifUnit: ifUnit };
                    jQuery.validator.methods.lowerThan100Percent.call(value, value, element[0], params);
                }
            });
```

All the arguments I send when calling the function pass as expected and the result of the return is also "False" and it suppose to show the error message, but it doesn't from some reason.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working example based on your code created in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gg52n6nd/)

The changes I have made are:

1. Added a form around the input and added `id` attributes to the form and the `input`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282680/jquery-validation-without-form-tag) for why this was done.
2. Wired up the custom validator method to the input:

   `//Initialize the validator 
   var validator = $('#validatorForm').validate({ // initialize the Plugin
       rules: {
           increaseBudgetByValue: {
               lowerThan100Percent: true
           }
       }

   });`
3. Finally, the validation must be triggered on the input element by invoking its `valid` method, this is done in the `click` handler. I set the contents of `span[data-review='Increase_budget_if_unit']` first sinjce `lowerThan100Percent` method is no longer invoked directly. You can also validate the entire form - this is how it's done usually.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have done what you suggested and it works , but there is another problem now. Because we  use: "$("#increaseBudgetByValue").valid()" and the input is required so on changing the span text it alerts "the input is required".

Comment: Have you modified the code ? I never see the "the input is required" error in my fiddle. Or maybe I am missing the correct steps ?

Comment: You can add an additional hidden span element to hold the value of the `ifUnit` instead of using the visible span element i.e. `span[data-review='Increase_budget_if_unit']`. `lowerThan100Percent` can the value of the hidden span

Comment: I added a condition that if that span is not empty then it should valid it. works.